# How to return value from promise and use it in another method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I have in class component three methods with promises. And I need to use the returned value from setNewJsonAndGetTranslate method in getTranslate, but it's return nothing

```
getTranslate(key) {
    return this.setNewJsonAndGetTranslate(key); //<-- I get undefined, because nothing returned from Promise
  }

  setNewJsonAndGetTranslate(key) {
    this.setJson().then(json => {
      let translate = TranslateService.jsonPathToValue(json, key);
      let result = JSON.stringify(translate[this.user.getLangCode()]);
      if (result !== undefined) {
        return result.substring(1, result.length - 1); //<-- I'm need to return this
      } else {
        return key;
      }
    });
  }


  setJson() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      $.getJSON(Environment.prefixPath + "assets/i18n.json", json => {
        let translate = JSON.stringify(json);
        window.localStorage.setItem("translate_json", translate);
        resolve(json);
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: You are not returning `this.setJson()...`

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're not returning anything from `setNewJsonAndTranslate`. `return` the asynchronous call:

```
return this.setJson().then(json => {...});
```

You could also use an `async` function and `await` the asynchronous code:

```
async setNewJsonAndGetTranslate(key) {
  let json = await this.setJson();
  let translate = TranslateService.jsonPathToValue(json, key);
  let result = JSON.stringify(translate[this.user.getLangCode()]);
  if (result !== undefined) {
    return result.substring(1, result.length - 1); //<-- I'm need to return this
  } else {
    return key;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But in that case, I get in console

getTranslate =  Promise {<pending>}

Comment: You need to use await or then when you're calling setNewJsonAndGetTranslate as well as within it.

Comment: Yes, I did it, but it's doesn't work
  async getTranslate(key) {
    return await this.setNewJsonAndGetTranslate(key);
  }

Comment: Post code where you are consuming getTranslate method

Comment: I use it in simple react component. I don't know how to put the pretty code in comment

    <div>
      {translateService.getTranslate("notifications.cookies_bar")}
    </div>